# ViewChildren on canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, typescript

I have a little question about the viewchildren. I am a bit lost. So I am able to use viewchild but view children is not working.

So basically the viewchild with 1 canvas:

In the HTML:

```
<canvas #mycan style="background:white; border: 1px solid black;" class='center'></canvas>
```

In the TS:

```
@ViewChild("mycan") myCanvas;
...
let canvas = this.myCanvas.nativeElement;
this.context = canvas.getContext("2d");
```

However for the view children I am a bit lost:

```
<ion-slide *ngFor="let card of cardList">
    <canvas #mycan style="background:white; border: 1px solid black;" class='center'></canvas>
</ion-slide>
```

And in my TS:

```
@ViewChildren('mycan') canvas: QueryList<HTMLCanvasElement>;
...
for(var index in this.canvas){
let canvas = this.canvas[index].nativeElement;
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
```

The problem is that canvas is null.

I also tried by changing HTMLCanvasElement by ElementRef but it is not working :(

Do you maybe have an idea?

Thanks a lot!!! :)

Best regards

Geoffrey MUSELLI

Comment: Quick thought, try removing the quotes around `'mycan'` in the `@ViewChildren` decorator?

Comment: I cannot unfortunately. there is a typescript error if i do it

Comment: You should query ViewChildren with ElementRef. Then you will get access to elements on ngAfterViewInit hook.